# Cannot change /etc/hosts in docker container with read_only root filesystem

Tags: docker, hostname, kubernetes, docker-compose, read-only

I am trying to add a line in `/etc/hosts` file with a specific IP and a hostname. The IP is static and the hostname is retrievable from the `/etc/hostname`.

However, I want my root file system to be read-only.

So I get the following error:
`/etc/hosts: Read-only file system`

When I check with `mount` it is: `ro`.

So, I try to add `/etc/hosts` as an `emptydir`, but it is not allowed since `/etc/hosts` is already mounted with error:
`b'linux mounts: Duplicate mount point: /etc/hosts`

I am also trying to remove `/etc/hosts` in the dockerfile and symblink it to another file but I get the following error:
`rm: cannot remove '/etc/hosts': Device or resource busy`

If I don't mount as read_only the filesystem, the `/etc/hosts` is not `rw`, and I can normally make the change.
Then, the `/etc/hosts` is not mounted as `ro` but `rw`. So this value is inherited.

I am using kubernetes manifest or docker compose to deploy the container image and I have concluded that I need something like the --add-host in docker, but retrieve the hostname dynamically from /etc/hostname.

```
    In `docker-compose`:
    extra_hosts:
      - "hostname:127.0.1.1"

    In `kubernetes-yaml`:
    hostAliases:
      - ip: "127.0.1.1"
        hostnames:
        - "hostname"
```

Is there a way to get the hostname as a variable in docker-compose and yaml?

Is there another way to bypass the `ro` mounted `/etc/hosts` file when the rootfile system is readonly?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am using the container to deploy two LDAP servers (master/slave). Server startup fails with error: Sync context connect error: "Name or service not known".

Comment: The same think happens with /dev. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35041 Maybe that should be an issue in docker repository.

Comment: Does this issue is still valid? Did you resolve it? Which Kubernetes version did you use then?